# Call Qt object method from another std::thread

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, c++11

I have simple Qt form which represents main window of my app. It has method:

```
void gui_popup::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    QString text = ui->MainText->toPlainText();
    text = "1\n" + text;
    ui->MainText->setText(text);
}
```

Also I have some code, running in another thread, created like this:

```
std:thread* core_thread = new thread(&Init); //void Init()...
```

Then, at some moment or condition code from *std::thread* need to call *gui_popup::on_pushButton_clicked()*. I'm trying to do it like this:

```
void test_callback(void* object_ptr)
{
    auto this_object = (gui_popup*)object_ptr;
    this_object->on_pushButton_clicked();
}
```

In std::thread code I'm saving *test_callback* pointer and *gui_popup* object pointer. But when it starts calling *on_pushButton_clicked()* program halts with segmentation fault error. This code works fine with some other simple classes, but not with QtObject. What am I doing wrong?

**UPDATE:**
I've solved it this way:

```
void test_callback(void* object_ptr)
{
    QMetaObject qtmo;
    qtmo.invokeMethod((gui_popup*)object_ptr, "on_pushButton_clicked");
}
```

it is, of course, much more complex than using QThread, emitting signals and all other suggested solutions. However thank you everyone for trying to help.

Comment: you need to emit the signal, not call the function directly

Comment: With QThread you can do this very easy and safe with signals and slots. Is there option that you can't use Qthread + worker QObject subclass?

Comment: @BЈовић can you provide example how to emit signal for some slot?

Comment: @AlekDepler first, you define signal in header, then you `emit clickPushButton();` and you catch it with connect statement.

Comment: Don't forget guys, that we can use Qt signals and slots only in QObject subclass and only with Q_OBJECT macro.

Comment: @Shf, I've tried to do it like "emit this_object->on_pushButton_clicked();" - still halts

Comment: @AlekDepler nope, you define in header of your worker class some singnal `void finishedSignal();` Next you run instance of worker in new thread (with a moveToThread() ). Next, you connect your worker's `finishedSignal()` to slot in main (GUI) class, that modifies UI, like your `on_pushButton_clicked()`

Comment: @AlekDepler your solution is not that complex. By using `invokeMethod ` you push a metaevent in the Qthread event queue. Which is what happens when using signal and slots.

Comment: @AlekDepler Please add the solution as an answer, not in the question.

Comment: Create minimal example to reproduce the problem. What you posted is not enough. How to emit a signal, you can find in any qt tutorial (there are so many examples)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I usually solve it like this:

```
class Foo : public QObject
{
   Q_OBJECT

     Foo()
     {
       // connect to own signal to own slot and hence "translate" it
       connect(this, SIGNAL(some_signal(QString)),
               this, SLOT(some_slot(QString)));
     }

   signals:
     void some_signal(QString s);

   protected slots:
     void some_slot(QString s)
     {
        // do something with your gui
     }
   public: 
     void callback_proxy(std::string s)
     {
        emit some_signal(QString::fromUtf8(m_string.c_str()));
     }
};
```

and then the tread does not need to know about QT:

```
void thread_run_function(Foo* foo)
{
    foo->callback_proxy("Hello from Thread!");
}
```

As far as I understood this is save because the connect (signal,slot) does have a additional default parameter (`Qt::ConnectionType` type which defaults to `Qt::AutoConnection`). This tells QT to dispach signals into the qt main event loop if they originate from a foreign thread. Note that using this connection type essentialy makes qt decide on runtime whether to dispatch the signal or call the slot immediately.

HtH Martin

Edits: Some more info on default parameter and this link as reference:
See http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt.html#ConnectionType-enum